# Fullpage.js not working properly when responsiveWidth is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I have a fullpage.js implementation with three sections and it works fine in desktops.
I have disabled fullpage.js when the screen goes beyond 600px. I do that like so as suggested in the documentation

```
responsiveWidth: 600
```

But when I do scroll now,there is some glitch like 
1.Scroll down to one section,and it automatically scrolls up half the screen to the previous section.
2. I can't scroll to the last section,if I do scroll and within a second the second last section comes up.

here is my code.

JS

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke']
            /*Adding function to display the current nav-item using afterLoad Callback -> fullPage.js*/

        , afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
            var loadedSection = $(this);
            if (index == 1) {
                $('.selectedMenu').remove();
                $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active selectedMenu animated fadeInRight\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + "Home" + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
            }
            if (index == 2) {
                $('.selectedMenu').remove();
                $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active selectedMenu animated fadeInRight\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + "Products" + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
            }
            if (index == 3) {
                $('.selectedMenu').remove();
                $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active selectedMenu animated fadeInRight\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + "Contact" + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
            }
        }
        , responsiveWidth: 600
    });
    /*click to reach anywhere in the page using #moveto callBack -> fullPage.js*/
    $(document).on('click', '#moveToHome', function () {
        $('.selectedMenu').remove();
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1);
        $(".navbar-toggler").click();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#moveToProducts', function () {
        $('.selectedMenu').remove();
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(2);
        $(".navbar-toggler").click();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#moveToContact', function () {
        $('.selectedMenu').remove();
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(3);
        $(".navbar-toggler").click();
    });
    $(".navbar-toggler").click(function () {
        $('.selectedMenu').remove();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section homeClass" id="home">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section productsClass" id="products">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 left">.col-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 middle">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 right">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section contactClass" id="contact">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
        <!--<div id="footer">Footer</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't have any css related to fullpage.js except for this,

```
#products .fp-tableCell {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle or codepen? The [responsive demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html) seems to be working fine.

Comment: Hey. I found the issue to be in the `afterLoad` callback,is there any way to remove the `afterLoad` call back using the `afterResponsive` call back? Like If  responsive is true,afterLoad should be working if it is false the afterLoad call back should be triggered.

Comment: @Alvaro,this is really important. I have found another issue,in the `afterResponsive` it says `true` if it is not responsive and vice-versa. But first try to give me a solution about disabling `afterLoad` through `afterResponsive`

Comment: My Bad,it was due to the animation which was happening on the nav-items.